# how to call back to a web service periodically

Tags: ios, web-services

I wnt to call to my webservice once every 45sec. Actually what I want to do is, user start to play some music within my application if user playing a song, every 45sec app should send a call to web service saying "User playing a song" likewise. I dont have any idea about iOS threads. So can anybody tell me how can I do this? Do I need to do threads or are there any other way to do this?

Thankyou

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18546627/perform-task-on-background-thread-in-ios-keep-execution-running-even-app-enters/18546680#18546680   have a look at this, i think it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some code to help you.

Set a `NSTimer` somewhere, like in `viewDidLoad`, to run every 45secs, performing your web service call:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:45.0
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(callService)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];
```

And then implement the selector used in the timer, running some code in background, as you want:

```
-(void)callService
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

       //Code in this part is run on a background thread, call your service here

   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform this action on background thread. So it wont affect the UI. User can perform any other action. For that you may want to use an `NSTimer` and `performSelectorInBackground: withObject:`. Using an `NSTimer` You can repeatedly call a method. From that call the web service method in background. `GCD` also a better option.

Comment: do u have any example for that? because I dont have proper idea about that?

Comment: Dont have example. NSTimer is very simple also GCD. Give a try and get back to me