# iOS: continue background thread execution even when app is minimised

Tags: ios, background-process

As the title says, I am working on a app where I need to continue a database operation initiated from **AppDelegate**'s `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method even if the home button is pressed and the app entered background.

I am consulting [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW23) Apple doc and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18546680/3336675) StackOverflow answer, but couldn't find a way that suits me.

My current code goes this way:

In `AppDelegate.m` file:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
//some work here and then

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{

        [database createTable];
        [strongSelf populateDictionary];
    }); //this thread is executed only once a lifetime (I have handled that)

    return YES;
}
```

Here, basically I am creating a database table and populating it. But I want it to be keep on running even if the app is minimised.

So, do I need to do something in `- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application` or something else! I don't know. Kindly help.

Regards.

Comment: How long does your task take to finish?

Comment: about 25 to 30 seconds @user523234